# Потеря файлов на флешке. Иероглифы в именах

Tags: хранение-данных

Файлы, которые вчера создал на флешке, сегодня оказались повреждены.
Вместо имён иероглифы и отсутствовал доступ.

После **chkdsk** получил сообщение что файлы найдены и помещены в папку FOUND.
Но папки FOUND на флешке нет (cистемные и скрытые файлы включены).
Пробовал на другом компе - пусто.
Сделал поиск по типу файлов .**chk**, такие должны появляться в папке FOUND - пусто.

Более того, сама папка с повреждёнными файлами теперь пропала!
Повторил **chkdsk** - теперь пишет что всё в норме.

Использовал Active File Recovery и GetDataBack.
Обе программы находят кучу файлов, даже полугодичной давности в хорошем состоянии.
Но повреждённых и потерянных день назад не находят.

Как мне вернуть эти файлы, теперь хотя бы в повреждённом виде?
Что ещё попробовать?